# $\mathbb Z_N$ (discrete) gauge theory

Tags: resource-recommendations, mathematical-physics, gauge-theory, discrete, lattice-gauge-theory

I am currently trying to go through some literature on symmetry protected topological phases and gauge theories defined on lattices. I am looking for a mathematically precise reference that discusses $\mathbb Z_N$ gauge theory. Or more generally, a resource that discusses *discrete* gauge theories where the underlying group is a finite, discrete group.

Any recommendations?

Comment: The original [Dijkgraaf-Witten paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-129/issue-2/Topological-gauge-theories-and-group-cohomology/cmp/1104180750.full) is pretty solid